# Copying keyframes to complete walk cycle

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes, dopesheet

I am almost done blocking my walk cycle. However, when I try to copy frame 3 and paste it on frame 15 using "paste flipped," I do not get the desired result. His hands/feet do not copy over correctly. I need to do this for frame 15, 18 and 21. Thank you.

File: https://we.tl/t-WE6SL1gLSj

Frame 3 copied:
[image]

Frame 3 pasted on frame 15 with "paste flipped" option.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Blender does only flip pose correctly if you name your bones correctly. So you have to rename them to blabla.R and blabla.L

video explanation: https://youtu.be/yTW3QI7T52g

Comment: Are you referring to the hand/finger bones? If so, does this mean I have to create a new walk cycle?

Comment: no, just rename them with e.g. Blenders internal "batch rename" tool [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/biwrB.gif